# Unpacking a list/string of hex values into integers

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, hex, unpack

I'm trying to unapck a list from hex to integers in python.

So for example:

```
hexValues = '\x90\x82|uj\x82ix'
decodedHex = struct.unpack_from('B', hexValues,0)
print decodedHex
```

Which would print (144,) and nothing else. Is there any way I can loop through this string to get all values? (bear in mind the length of hex values is much longer than the example given.)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the values at once:

```
import struct

hexValues = '\x90\x82|uj\x82ix'
format = '%dB' % len(hexValues)
decodedHex = struct.unpack_from(format, hexValues)
print(decodedHex)  # -> (144, 130, 124, 117, 106, 130, 105, 120)
```

As Jon Clements helpfully pointed out in a comment, you don't really need to use the `struct` module:

```
decodedHex = tuple(bytearray(hexValues))
print(decodedHex)  # -> (144, 130, 124, 117, 106, 130, 105, 120)
```

Comment: Possible alternative `list(bytearray(hexValues))`

Comment: This is great thanks! Any idea why so many values are printed? I thought \x is an escape character indicating the next two characters are hexadecimal values. Only 3 integers should be returned?

Comment: @javasaucebiner you'll get as many as `len(hexValues)` - what were you expecting?

Comment: @javasaucebiner: there are 8 characters, so 8 byte values.

Comment: @javasaucebiner: `|`, `u`, `j`, etc. are all printable ASCII values, so are not displayed with `\xhh` escape sequences. They are not part of the `\xhh` sequences, which are always 2 hex digits long.

Comment: javasaucebiner: Because `struct.unpack()` always returns a tuple of values, even in the code in your question it's returning one , but it only contains a single value — `(144,)` — because your format string specifies only one byte.

Comment: @JonClements   I am trying to get IQ data. I don't know if any of you know about this. But, do you think 144 = I value, 130 = Q value 124 = I Value etc?

Comment: @javasaucebiner if you're aware of the criteria - surely you can work with the values this answer provides and that's your next challenge? :p

Comment: What criteria? sorry? I was just hoping for confirmarion

Comment: @martineau I don't follow. I'm trying to find the IQ values to plot a graph. I will perform an operation on these values to return a value between -1 and +1.

Comment: Hi @martineau, could you please explain the line 

'%dB' % len(hexValues)

Comment: javasaucebiner: It creates a string with the decimal number of hex values in the `hexValues` string followed by a the character `B` which is the [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) for the **unsigned char** type. If you read the documentation under the table of format characters it says that they may be preceded by an integral repeat count, so for example, a format string of `"2B"` means unpack 2 values interpreting each as an unsigned 8-bit value between 0-255. For that case, it does the same thing as the literal `"BB"` would.